# When I set an event in fullcalendar how do I remove this gap on the right

Tags: fullcalendar

[image: This Gap]

This gap right here highlighted in red

preferably the change is only in the day view

FullCalendar Version 4.3.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

override this style

`.fc-direction-ltr .fc-timegrid-col-events { margin: 0 2.5% 0 2px; }`

either match the left and right gaps

`.fc-direction-ltr .fc-timegrid-col-events { margin: 0 2px 0 2px; }`

or have no gaps at all

`.fc-direction-ltr .fc-timegrid-col-events { margin: 0; }`

make it day specific by changing to

`.fc-timeGridDay-view .fc-timegrid-col-events { margin: 0; }`

Correct for **FullCalendar v5**

--

update, this should work for **v4**

override this

`.fc-ltr .fc-time-grid .fc-event-container { margin: 0 2.5% 0 2px; }`

to either match left and right

`.fc-ltr .fc-time-grid .fc-event-container { margin: 0 2px 0 2px; }`

or no gaps at all

`.fc-ltr .fc-time-grid .fc-event-container { margin: 0; }`

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work for my version 4.3.1

Comment: I have added a v4 version to my answer, which hopefully should work for you @IDK